# .htaccess Change Has Shutdown My Wordpress Website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, shutdown

I used this template in my sites' .htaccess and now my site has a 500 error

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?your domain name\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.your domain name.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I deleted the template and yet my site still has a 500 error. Please Help !!!!

Thank You :D

Answer (score 0):

Clear the htaccess file and change the settings from admin to default ( in which link works like   ?page_id=2 etc.. )   and try now , it will work again.

If you need seo friendly URL then again change the setting and wordpress will write the htaccess file automatically

Comment: I don't understand, please elaborate :D